# Sling quartz heartbeat gives exceptions in Hearthandler

Tags: java, jackrabbit, sling

When I have a running sling instance I get a funny 
Exception during job execution of

> org.apache.sling.discovery.impl.common.heartbeat.HeartbeatHandler@6dd08975 : Exception while talking to repository (org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Unable to commit changes to session.) java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while talking to repository (org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Unable to commit changes to session.)

What tools/techniques should I use to make it beat with a right rate ?

Comment: Looks like a bug, do you have a scenario that would allow us to reproduce it? Please indicate the relevant versions or svn revision numbers.

Comment: Yep, use CQ 5.6.1. Prepare 4-5 content packages of about 800MB. And from different browser tab start installing them. At the same time launch Tree Activation on the paths that are still being added. Result: reproduced reliably.

Comment: Ok, I have mentioned this issue on the sling dev mailing list, let's see if someone has more info about it ( http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sling-dev/ )